# wordpress with xampp works fine in lan but

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

wordpress with xampp works fine in lan but when i try from outside network, it seems like this
[image: prtscr]

i've checked log files. there is nothing in error.log. and in access.log a few line of logs are created for every request, like these;

```
85.xxx.xx.xx - - [14/Sep/2014:01:47:47 +0300] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
85.xxx.xx.xx - - [14/Sep/2014:01:48:09 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/09/6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1266 "95.xx.xxx.xx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
85.xxx.xx.xx - - [14/Sep/2014:01:50:26 +0300] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
85.xxx.xx.xx - - [14/Sep/2014:01:50:48 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/09/6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1266 "95.xx.xxx.xx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
85.xxx.xx.xx - - [14/Sep/2014:01:51:09 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/09/6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1266 "95.xx.xxx.xx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
```

i tried after closing firewall completely but nothing changed. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with PHP. This issue is with APACHE. Make sure that your apache is able to allow access to all the folders and files where you are getting this 404 errors.

Comment: there may be a problem with mysql? here is a 

[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zaoUg34.png)

Comment: 404 error wont ouccur generally due to mysql. You will errors starting from 5xx if thats the case. Internal Server Error